# Verifying Twilio Outgoing Caller IDs with SMS

Tags: twilio, telephony, twilio-api

I can see from the [Twilio Voice API Reference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/outgoing-caller-ids) the `OutgoingCallerIds` resource enables programatic verification of Caller IDs with a voice call made to the user's phone.

The Twilio Console allows verification of Caller IDs via both voice and text so hoping: Is there a parameter to enable programatic verification via text as well?

Answer (score 2):

Just had confirmation from a Twilio engineer that confirming via text is not possible. Twilio might be introducing text based confirmation of CallerID down the line though.

---

#### Update

One work around our Twilio Account Manager offered is to approve us for any phone number and that we then introduce our own phone number validation which can of course include text based confirmation.

The onus would be on us to ensure we handle bad actors attempting phone number spoofing. We did not proceed down that route and just used call based validation.

Comment: Hey, any update so far on this from Twilio ? I'm also in need of sms based verified caller ids?

Comment: Do you find any solution on this please help ?

Comment: Any updates on text-based caller-ID verification? I don't understand why Twilio uses them in their consoles but not allow end-user to use them.

Comment: Umm, still doesn't make sense because it's sounds practically the same thing whether we're the one doing the validation or Twilio. I played around with the Twilio's Verify API, and it'd fit quite well for doing something like that ourselves.